# how do i fix this code that _ insert zone, delete_zone, print_zone

Tags: c

**For the creation of the map, the user is left with the possibility of requesting the following four functions via a menu with one (switch):**
Insertion of a zone at the end of the insert_zone function list. It creates the new zone in dynamic memory malloc, inserts it in the list by modifying the value of the next_zone pointer of the last land in the list with the result of the malloc. The type of the zone as well as the object found within the zone are randomly generated: all zones are equiprobable, no_object has a 40% probability while the other objects in the enum Object_type_zone have equal probability. Finally, the enum field Tipo_prova prova will be inserted with a certain probability every time a player arrives in a given zone see function advance .

Delete the last zone inserted in the path cancel_zone

Print the fields of all the zones created up to that moment print_map.

i leaves the possibility to the user to use a menu to perform the following four functions:
insert_zone: delete_zone: print_map;
.
I leave a copy of the file.h (works well); "**you can help to find the solution for the problem"**

```
#ifndef H_GAMELIB
#define H_GAMELIB


extern void imposta_gioco();
extern void gioca();
extern void termina_gioco();
extern void inserisci_zona();
extern void stampa_mappa();
extern void chiudi_mappa();
extern void cancella_zona();


enum Tipo_Difficolta { dilettante, intermedio, incubo };
enum Tipo_oggetto_iniziale { EMF, spirit_box, videocamera, calmanti, sale };
enum Tipo_oggetto_zona { adrenalina, cento_dollari, coltello, calmanti1, nessun_oggetto };
enum Tipo_zona { caravan, cucina, soggiorno, camera, bagno, garage, seminterrato };
enum Tipo_prova { prova_EMF, prova_spirit_box, prova_videocamera, nessuna_prova };

struct Zona_mappa {
    enum Tipo_zona zona;
    enum Tipo_prova prova;
    enum Tipo_oggetto_zona oggetto_zona;
    struct Zona_mappa* prossima_zona;
};

struct Giocatore {
    char nome_giocatore[30];
    unsigned char sanita_mentale;
    struct Zona_mappa* posizione;
    unsigned char zaino[4];
};


 

#endif



main.c

#include "gamelib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <time.h>




int main (void){
 unsigned short numero;
 int c = 0;

  printf("\033[1;35m    ____ ____ ____ ____ ____ ____ ____ ____ \n");
  printf("   ||P |||h |||a |||l |||s |||o |||P |||h ||\n");
  printf("   ||__|||__|||__|||__|||__|||__|||__|||__||\n");
  printf("   |/__\\|/__\\|/__\\|/__\\|/__\\|/__\\|/__\\|/__\\|\n");
  printf("\033[0m\n");
  printf("||preme 'invio' per continuare||\n");
     
     while(getchar()!= '\n');
    
     do{
    printf("\n");
    printf("> \033[1;93m1\033[1m: Imposta Gioco.\n");
    printf("> \033[1;96m2\033[2m: Gioca.\n");
    printf("> \033[1;91m3\033[3m: Termina gioco.\n\n");

  printf ("\033[92mScelta:\033[0m ");
     scanf("%hu",&numero);
     while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF); //pulizia dei buffer

     switch(numero){
        case 1: 
        printf("hai inserito il primo numero\n");
         imposta_gioco();
         break;
        case 2:
        printf("hai inserito il secondo numero\n");
         gioca();break;
        case 3:
        printf("hai inserito il terzo numero");
        termina_gioco();break;
        default: printf("\033[31mAttenzione!\033[0m Opzione non valida, per favore inserisci \033[31mun numero da 1 a 3\033[0m.\n");
        }
         }while (numero != 3);
               return 0;
              }
             
      
gamelib.c


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "gamelib.h"

#define ERROR_ARGS_NUM(_min, _max) printf("\033[31mAttenzione!\033[5m Opzione non valida, per favore inserisci \033[31mun numero da " #_min " a " #_max "\033[0m.\n")
#define CHECK_NUM_INPUT_RANGE(n, _min, _max)

struct Zona_mappa *pLast = NULL;
struct Zona_mappa *pFirst = NULL;
static struct Giocatore players[4];
static int nplayers = 0;
static int difficulty_level;

int ask_num(const char *prompt)
{
    if (prompt)
        printf("%s", prompt);

    int n;
    if (scanf("%d", &n) <= 0)
        n = -1;

    return n;
}
void mostra_zaino(struct Giocatore *giocatore)
{
    const char *nome_oggetto_iniziale;
    switch (giocatore->zaino[0])
    {
    case EMF:
        nome_oggetto_iniziale = "EMF";
        break;
    case spirit_box:
        nome_oggetto_iniziale = "Spirit Box";
        break;
    case videocamera:
        nome_oggetto_iniziale = "Videocamera";
        break;
    case calmanti:
        nome_oggetto_iniziale = "Calmanti";
        break;
    case sale:
        nome_oggetto_iniziale = "Sale";
        break;
    default:
        return;
    }
    printf("Contenuto zaino di %s:\nOggetto iniziale: %s\n", giocatore->nome_giocatore, nome_oggetto_iniziale);
    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
    {
        switch (giocatore->zaino[i])
        {
        case cento_dollari:
            printf("100$\n");
            break;
        case nessun_oggetto:
            printf("nessun_oggetto\n");
            break;
        case coltello:
            printf("coltello\n");
            break;
        case calmanti1:
            printf("calmanti1\n");
            break;
        case adrenalina:
            printf("adrenalina\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void imposta_gioco()
{

    srand(time(NULL));
    memset(players, 0, sizeof(players));
    nplayers = ask_num("Inserisci il numero di giocatori (da 1 a 4): ");
    CHECK_NUM_INPUT_RANGE(nplayers, 1, 4);

    printf("Scegli il livello di difficoltà:\n");
    printf("> \033[1;93m1\033[0m: Dilettante\n");
    printf("> \033[2;93m2\033[0m: Intermedio\n");
    printf("> \033[3;93m3\033[0m: Incubo\n");

    difficulty_level = ask_num("\033[32mInserisci il numero corrispondente: ");
    CHECK_NUM_INPUT_RANGE(difficulty_level, 1, 3);

    for (int i = 0; i < nplayers; i++)
    {
        printf("Inserisci il nome del giocatore %d: ", (i + 1));
        if (scanf("%s", players[i].nome_giocatore) <= 0)
            return;

        players[i].sanita_mentale = 100;
        players[i].zaino[0] = rand() % 5;
        for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++)
            players[i].zaino[j] = nessun_oggetto;

        mostra_zaino(&players[i]);
    }
}

struct Zona_mappa *genera_mappa()
{
    // Crea la prima zona mappa
    struct Zona_mappa *prima_zona = malloc(sizeof(struct Zona_mappa));
     prima_zona->zona = cucina;

    // Crea la seconda zona mappa
    struct Zona_mappa *seconda_zona = malloc(sizeof(struct Zona_mappa));
     seconda_zona->zona = soggiorno;
    prima_zona->prossima_zona = seconda_zona;

    // Crea la terza zona
    struct Zona_mappa *terza_zona = malloc(sizeof(struct Zona_mappa));
     terza_zona->zona = garage;
    seconda_zona->prossima_zona = terza_zona;

    struct Zona_mappa *quarta_zona = malloc(sizeof(struct Zona_mappa));
      quarta_zona->zona = camera;
    terza_zona->prossima_zona = quarta_zona;

    // Crea la terza zona
    struct Zona_mappa *quinta_zona = malloc(sizeof(struct Zona_mappa));
     quinta_zona->zona = bagno;
    quarta_zona->prossima_zona = quinta_zona;

    struct Zona_mappa *ultima_zona = malloc(sizeof(struct Zona_mappa));
     ultima_zona->zona = seminterrato;
    quinta_zona->prossima_zona = ultima_zona;

    ultima_zona->prossima_zona = prima_zona;
    // Assegna i valori ai puntatori globali
    pFirst = prima_zona;
    pLast = ultima_zona;
    printf("la lista è pronta\n");
    return prima_zona; // Restituisce l'indirizzo della prima zona
}
void inserisci_zona()
{
    struct Zona_mappa *nuova_zona = malloc(sizeof(struct Zona_mappa));
    if (nuova_zona == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERRORE di allocazione di memoria per la nuova zona\n");
        return;
    }
    nuova_zona->zona = rand() % 4;
    int r = rand() % 100;
    if (r < 80)
    {
        nuova_zona->zona = cucina;
    }
    else if (r < 60)
    {
        nuova_zona->zona = bagno;
    }
    else if (r < 50)
    {
        nuova_zona->zona = garage;
    }
    else if (r < 40)
    {
        nuova_zona->zona = seminterrato;
    }
    else if (r < 30)
    {
        nuova_zona->zona = camera;
    }
    else
    {
        nuova_zona->zona = soggiorno;
    }

    r = rand() % 100;
    if (r < 40)
    {
        nuova_zona->oggetto_zona = nessun_oggetto;
    }
    else if (r < 60)
    {
        nuova_zona->oggetto_zona = calmanti1;
    }
    else if (r < 70)
    {
        nuova_zona->oggetto_zona = coltello;
    }
    else if (r < 90)
    {
        nuova_zona->oggetto_zona = cento_dollari;
    }
    else
    {
        nuova_zona->oggetto_zona = adrenalina;
    }
// Insert the new zone at the end of the list
    if (pFirst == NULL)
    {// If the list is empty, set First and Last as the new zone
        pFirst = nuova_zona;
        pLast = nuova_zona;
        pLast->prossima_zona = pFirst;
    }
    else
    {
        pLast->prossima_zona = nuova_zona;
        pLast = nuova_zona;
        pLast->prossima_zona = pFirst;
    }
}

void cancella_zona()
{
// Special case: the list is empty
    if (pFirst == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

// Special case: the list contains a single zone
    if (pFirst == pLast)
    {
        free(pFirst);
        pFirst = NULL;
        pLast = NULL;
        return;
    }

   // Otherwise, find the last zone in the list and delete it
    struct Zona_mappa *p = pFirst;
    while (p->prossima_zona != pLast)
    {
        p = p->prossima_zona;
    }

    free(pLast);
    pLast = p;
    pLast->prossima_zona = pFirst;
}
void stampa_mappa()
{

    // Caso particolare: la lista è vuota
    if (pFirst == NULL)
    {
        printf("La mappa è vuota\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("Stampa della mappa:\n");
    struct Zona_mappa *p = pFirst;
    do
    {
        printf(" - Zona di tipo %d, con oggetto %d\n", p->zona, p->oggetto_zona);
        p = p->prossima_zona;
    } while (p != pFirst);
}

void chiudi_mappa()
{
    gioco_impostato = 1;
}

// Funzione che avvia il gioco
void gioca()
{
    {
    }
    
}

// Funzione che termina il gioco
void termina_gioco()
{
}
```

**I have problems in the following 3 blocks of code**

```
void inserisci_zona()
{
    struct Zona_mappa *nuova_zona = malloc(sizeof(struct Zona_mappa));
    if (nuova_zona == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERRORE di allocazione di memoria per la nuova zona\n");
        return;
    }
    nuova_zona->zona = rand() % 4;
    int r = rand() % 100;
    if (r < 80)
    {
        nuova_zona->zona = cucina;
    }
    else if (r < 60)
    {
        nuova_zona->zona = bagno;
    }
    else if (r < 50)
    {
        nuova_zona->zona = garage;
    }
    else if (r < 40)
    {
        nuova_zona->zona = seminterrato;
    }
    else if (r < 30)
    {
        nuova_zona->zona = camera;
    }
    else
    {
        nuova_zona->zona = soggiorno;
    }

    r = rand() % 100;
    if (r < 40)
    {
        nuova_zona->oggetto_zona = nessun_oggetto;
    }
    else if (r < 60)
    {
        nuova_zona->oggetto_zona = calmanti1;
    }
    else if (r < 70)
    {
        nuova_zona->oggetto_zona = coltello;
    }
    else if (r < 90)
    {
        nuova_zona->oggetto_zona = cento_dollari;
    }
    else
    {
        nuova_zona->oggetto_zona = adrenalina;
    }
// Insert the new zone at the end of the list
    if (pFirst == NULL)
    {// If the list is empty, set First and Last as the new zone
        pFirst = nuova_zona;
        pLast = nuova_zona;
        pLast->prossima_zona = pFirst;
    }
    else
    {
        pLast->prossima_zona = nuova_zona;
        pLast = nuova_zona;
        pLast->prossima_zona = pFirst;
    }
}
```

```
void cancella_zona()
{
// Special case: the list is empty
    if (pFirst == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

// Special case: the list contains a single zone
    if (pFirst == pLast)
    {
        free(pFirst);
        pFirst = NULL;
        pLast = NULL;
        return;
    }

   // Otherwise, find the last zone in the list and delete it
    struct Zona_mappa *p = pFirst;
    while (p->prossima_zona != pLast)
    {
        p = p->prossima_zona;
    }

    free(pLast);
    pLast = p;
    pLast->prossima_zona = pFirst;
}
```

```
void stampa_mappa()  
{

    // Caso particolare: la lista è vuota
    if (pFirst == NULL)
    {
        printf("La mappa è vuota\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("Stampa della mappa:\n");
    struct Zona_mappa *p = pFirst;
    do
    {
        printf(" - Zona di tipo %d, con oggetto %d\n", p->zona, p->oggetto_zona);
        p = p->prossima_zona;
    } while (p != pFirst);
}
```

Comment: Small thing: `inserisci_zona()`... 4 out of 5 numbers will be `< 80`, so almost every execution of `if (r < 80)` will be true...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the fixed code. Required modifications to fix the code are marked and explained with comments at the end of the lines starting with "// Edit:". It is a single file where I inserted the header file. At the end is a small main() to test the code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef H_GAMELIB
#define H_GAMELIB

void imposta_gioco (void);
void gioca         (void);
void termina_gioco (void);
void inserisci_zona(void);
void stampa_mappa  (void);
void chiudi_mappa  (void);
void cancella_zona (void);

enum Tipo_Difficolta       { dilettante, intermedio, incubo };
enum Tipo_oggetto_iniziale { EMF, spirit_box, videocamera, calmanti, sale };
enum Tipo_oggetto_zona     { adrenalina, cento_dollari, coltello, calmanti1, nessun_oggetto };
enum Tipo_zona             { caravan, cucina, soggiorno, camera, bagno, garage, seminterrato };
enum Tipo_prova            { prova_EMF, prova_spirit_box, prova_videocamera, nessuna_prova };

struct Zona_mappa {
    enum Tipo_zona         zona;
    enum Tipo_prova        prova;
    enum Tipo_oggetto_zona oggetto_zona;
    struct Zona_mappa*     prossima_zona;
};

struct Giocatore {
    char               nome_giocatore[30];
    unsigned char      sanita_mentale;
    struct Zona_mappa* posizione;
    unsigned char      zaino[4];
};

#endif

static struct Zona_mappa* pFirst = NULL;  // Edit: Added since pFirst was missing
static struct Zona_mappa* pLast  = NULL;  // Edit: Added since pLast was missing

void inserisci_zona(void) {
    struct Zona_mappa* nuova_zona = malloc(sizeof(struct Zona_mappa));
    if (nuova_zona == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR of memory allocation for the new zone\n");
        return;
    }
    nuova_zona->zona = rand() % 7;  // Edit: enum has 7 enumerators
    // Edit: Since zones are equiprobable, above line is sufficient
    /*
    int r = rand() % 100;
    if (r < 80)
    {
        nuova_zona->zona = cucina;
    }
    else if (r < 60)
    {
        nuova_zona->zona = bagno;
    }
    else if (r < 50)
    {
        nuova_zona->zona = garage;
    }
    else if (r < 40)
    {
        nuova_zona->zona = seminterrato;
    }
    else if (r < 30)
    {
        nuova_zona->zona = camera;
    }
    else
    {
        nuova_zona->zona = soggiorno;
    }
    */

    int r = rand() % 100;
    if (r < 40)
    {
        nuova_zona->oggetto_zona = nessun_oggetto;
    }
    else if (r < 55) // Edit: No object has 40% and all others 15%
    {
        nuova_zona->oggetto_zona = calmanti1;
    }
    else if (r < 70)
    {
        nuova_zona->oggetto_zona = coltello;
    }
    else if (r < 85) // Edit: No object has 40% and all others 15%
    {
        nuova_zona->oggetto_zona = cento_dollari;
    }
    else
    {
        nuova_zona->oggetto_zona = adrenalina;
    }
    // Insert the new zone at the end of the list
    if (pFirst == NULL)
    {
        // If the list is empty, set First and Last as the new zone
        pFirst = nuova_zona;
        pLast = nuova_zona;
        pLast->prossima_zona = NULL; // Edit: Next of last one has to be NULL
    }
    else
    {
        pLast->prossima_zona = nuova_zona;
        pLast = nuova_zona;
        pLast->prossima_zona = NULL; // Edit: Next of last one has to be NULL
    }
}


void cancella_zona(void) {
    // Special case: the list is empty
    if (pFirst == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Special case: the list contains a single zone
    if (pFirst == pLast)
    {
        free(pFirst);
        pFirst = NULL;
        pLast = NULL;
        return;
    }

   // Otherwise, find the second to last zone in the list
    struct Zona_mappa *p = pFirst;
    while (p->prossima_zona != pLast)
    {
        p = p->prossima_zona;
    }

    free(pLast);
    pLast = p;
    pLast->prossima_zona = NULL;  // Edit: Next of last zone has to be NULL
}

void stampa_mappa(void) {

    // Special case: the list is empty
    if (pFirst == NULL)
    {
        printf("The map is empty\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("Map printing:\n");
    struct Zona_mappa *p = pFirst;
    do
    {
        printf(" - Zone of type %d, with object %d\n", p->zona, p->oggetto_zona);
        p = p->prossima_zona;
    } while (p != NULL);  // Edit: Iterate until there's no next Zona_mappa which is the case if next is NULL
}

int main(void) {
  stampa_mappa();
  inserisci_zona();
  inserisci_zona();
  inserisci_zona();
  stampa_mappa();
  cancella_zona();
  stampa_mappa();
  cancella_zona();
  cancella_zona();
  stampa_mappa();
  for (;;);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake while gluing the code, I removed that part and inserted all the code written so far. I keep trying but I can't solve this problem, what do you suggest I do?

Comment: @aminesalhi The code I posted works standalone. Can you describe your problem? Unfortunately, I can't help without knowing what your problem is.

Comment: hi i modified the code like you told me, the code works thanks a lot ^^

Comment: @aminesalhi Great to hear it's working now. If you have questions why I did it like this, feel free to ask me. And could you please mark my answer as accepted? This would help me a lot in earning reputation.

Comment: don't worry the code in the code you explained it well and I understood thank you very much @micheal